# while updating grid view not updating all table

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, gridview

i am working on windows from application..i am filling my data grid view like this:

```
 Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName,l.LocName as Location,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as Phone,d.dtEmail as Email,l.Locid from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId  join Location_tbl l on l.Locid=c.locid where d.Deleted =0 and c.Deleted=0 order by cid", con.connect)

        dt1 = New DataTable
        bSource = New BindingSource
        adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
        bSource.DataSource = dt1
        gv.DataSource = bSource
        gv.Columns("cid").Visible = False
        gv.Columns("dtId").Visible = False
        gv.Columns("Locid").Visible = False
```

in update button I have code like this:

```
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter()

        Dim cid As Integer
        Dim dtid As Integer
        Dim cmpname As String
        Dim dtname As String
        Dim dtPhone As String
            Dim dtEmail As String
            Dim LocName As String

            Dim Locid As Integer

        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2

            Dim rv = DirectCast(gv.Rows(i).DataBoundItem, DataRowView)
            cid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Cid")

            dtid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("dtId")
                cmpname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")
                LocName = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Location")
            dtname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Department")
            dtPhone = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Phone")
            dtEmail = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("Email")
                Locid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Locid")


                adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName", con.connect)
                adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("Update Location_tbl Set LocName=@LocName where Locid=@Locid ", con.connect)

adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("update DepartmentMaster_tbl set dtName = @dtName,dtPhone = @dtPhone,dtEmail = @dtEmail where dtId=@dtid", con.connect)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpname)
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocName", LocName)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtId", dtid)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtName", dtname)
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Locid", Locid)

            adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Next
```

while clicking update button I am not getting any error..i can able to update my DepartmentMaster_tbl..but that is not updating my Location_tbl..what is wrong with my code..
any help is very appreciable..thanks

Answer (score 1):

because you are overwriting your UpdateCommands then doing ExecuteNonQuery which will use the current UpdateCommand available (the last one in this case)

Comment: you need to understand the comment and write the code accordingly... we cannot write the code for you otherwise you will not learn :)

Answer (score 0):

to me it looks like you are overwriting the *UpdateCommand* twice after setting it.
you set it with `UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl` then overwrite it with `UPDATE Location_tbl` and then overwrite it again with `update DepartmentMaster_tbl`,
as expected only the last one is executed.

a solution using `SqlCommand` instead of `SqlAdapter`:

```
using (SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection("connection string")
{
    DBConn.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction DBTran = DBConn.BeginTransaction)
    {
        using (SqlCommand DBCmd = new SqlCommand("your first statement here", DBConn))
        {
            DBCmd.Transaction = DBTran;
            // set only the parameters needed for this table
            ...
            // execute statement
            DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        // repeat the above block for the other tables
        ...
        // commit transaction to database
        DBTran.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: sir I understood what is wrong..now I want to know how I can update all table in one query,,

Comment: @user3262364 i'm not a big supporter of SQL code embedded (i'll go with a stored procedure instead) but i would go with 3 separate SqlCommand objects, one for each table with a shared transaction.

Comment: sir here I can set parameter like this right?  DBCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocName", LocName)

Comment: @user3262364 you can find a detailed answer on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)